# How can I send terminal escape sequences in raw input mode?

Tags: c, terminal, escaping, sequence

I have a program that uses a terminal in raw mode and I want to move the cursor around. Where can I find the escape sequence for this and how can I send it to the terminal from inside my c program?

Here's what I currently have:

```
char code[4];
code[0] = 27;
code[1] = 91;
code[2] = '*';
code[3] = 'D';
write(1, code, 4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want control of the full screen then you should look at the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library. This is a simple library for full screen console programs that contains among other things

- Full screen positioning of text
- Use of the full keyboard including function keys, insert/delete etc
- Use of attributes for colouring, highlighting of text etc

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [termcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) to get this information, as it varies, depending on what sort of terminal the user is at.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look hard at the [curses](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9693989999/toc.pdf) or [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses) libraries, and plan to use one or the other rather than roll your own.  You should aim to use the [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) system of terminal descriptions rather than the older [termcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) system.  See also the O'Reilly books "[Termcap and Terminfo](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780937175224)" and my favourite title (mainly because I seem to spend a lot of time cursing when programming) "[Progamming With Curses](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780937175026)".  (However, that book is ancient - 1986 - and there are other more recent books on the same subject which would probably be better choices; I still love the title, though.)